# Compilation with XeTex yields wrong chapter number

Tags: xetex, pdftex, numbering, input

I have a driver file for my thesis and all the chapters are included with `\input` commands. I noticed that only in the **sixth chapter** the section numbers are false, although they are displayed correctly in the ** table of contents**. I get ** 0.1 Nanoslits ** when I should be getting ** 6.1 Nanoslits **.

The compilation is done on Windows 10 64-bit with TexLive 2016 full installation. After a lot of tinkering I got an example that reproduces the issue and of short length. Here is the **MWE** and here is the associated [class file](https://paste.ee/p/p8WGG):

```
\documentclass[titlepage, footnotes, a4paper]{kuthesismod} 
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
    \usepackage{unicode-math} 
    \setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,Ligatures=Common,Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
    \setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\else  
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
    \usepackage[oldstyle]{libertine} 
    \usepackage{libertinust1math}
\fi
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\newcommand{\figref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tabref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{Equation~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\chapref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand*\chem[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}} 
\emergencystretch = 1 em
\begin{document}
    \prelimpages
    \tableofcontents
    \textpages
    \chapter{Introduction}\label{chp:intro}
        \section{Literature Review}

        \section{Thesis Outline}

    \chapter{Background Information}\label{chp:bg}
        \section{Brief review of electromagnetic theory}

        \section{Permittivities of metals}

            \subsection{Lorentz Model}

            \subsection{Drude Model}

            \subsection{Extended Drude Model}

        \section{Plasmons}

            \subsection{Volume Plasmons}

            \subsection{Surface Plasmon Polaritons}

        \chapter{Single Scatterers}\label{chp:singlescat}

        \section{Single Grating}

        \section{Rectangular Nanoslit}

        \section{\texorpdfstring{$\Delta$}{Delta}-antenna} 

    \chapter{SPP beam launcher}\label{chp:sppbeam}

        \section{Reproduction of Hermite-Gauss SPP Beam} 

        \section{Stripe Waveguide Coupling}

    \chapter{Scalar Wave Theory}\label{chp:scalarwave} 

        \section{Antenna Arrays} 

            \subsection{Linear Arrays}

            \subsection{Coupler Design}

        \chapter{Mode Coupling}\label{chp:modecoup}

        \section{Nanoslits}

        \section{\texorpdfstring{$\Delta$-antennas}{Delta-antennas}}

            \subsection{\texorpdfstring{Design with $w_b$ = 500 nm, $h$ = 800 nm }{Design 1}}

            \subsection{\texorpdfstring{Design with $w_b$ = 900 nm, $h$ = 800 nm }{Design 2}}

            \subsection{\texorpdfstring{Design with $w_b$ = 900 nm, $h$ = 800 nm with SPP on air-metal}{Design 3}}

    \chapter{Conclusion and Future Work}\label{chp:conc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And do you think by omitting the relevant code of `chapter1.tex` we're able to give more than guesses only? ;-)

Comment: I think it is because of the Gremlins which are hiding in that file.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry providing it ASAP.

Comment: @Skillmon I have added chapter1.tex source code as a link.

Comment: Which document class do you use? How or were is `\chapref` defined?

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of `80 \si{\micro\meter}`, you should write `\SI{80}{\micro\meter}`. If nothing else, that'll ensure you'll never have a line break between the number and its associated unit.

Comment: there is no way that anyone can answer this question, you need to cut the example down so it just needs two or three (small) chapter files and put the full code of all needed files into code sections in the question.

Comment: @Mico The `\chapref` command is defined in the preamble. Document class is a modified book class and I have included the chapter definitions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I could not exactly pinpoint the faulty chapter and I will provide the example when I can, otherwise it would be pretty bulky. Sometimes different combinations of inputted chapters work and I also tried a flattened version which exactly has the same misbehavior.

Comment: @Vesnog well either you need to debug it, or if you ask someone else to debug it you need to show them the code to debug. There is no point posting code that can not be run and may not be related to the problem and asking people to debug a document only you have.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay I think I got a MWE that is minimal and uploaded it here.

Comment: @HenriMenke Sorry for the inconvenience I thought it might be a common problem and I was trying to pinpoint the issue. I have provided a MWE that has wrong chapter number in chapter 6 when compiled with XeTex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

xelatex is finding the wrong font. If one load the font by name as done in David's example

> This is a more minimal example just using article class, it gives [6]
>   with pdftex and luatex and [0] with xetex.
>
> anyone feel free to pick up this example, if you want to answer (I'll
>   delete this if someone's posted an answer when I next come by:-)
>
> ```
> \documentclass{article} 
>
> \ifx\Umathchar\undefined
>     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
>     \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
>     \usepackage[oldstyle]{libertine} 
>     \usepackage{libertinust1math}
> \else  
>     \usepackage{fontspec} 
>     \setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,Ligatures=Common]{Linux Libertine O}
> \fi
>
> \begin{document}
>
>
> [{\bfseries\slshape 6}]
>
>
> \end{document}
> ```

it uses `LinLibertine_RZI.otf` instead of the correct `LinLibertine_RBI.otf` and this hasn't the correct numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\font\test= "[LinLibertine_RBI.otf]:script=latn;language=DFLT;+onum;"

\test 6 1234567890

\font\test= "Linux Libertine O/BI/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;+onum;"

\test 6 1234567890

\font\test= "[LinLibertine_RZI.otf]:script=latn;language=DFLT;+onum;"

\test 6 1234567890

\end{document}
```

[image]

So you should load at least this font by file name instead than by font name. E.g. by loading it through the libertine package or manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,Ligatures=Common, 
            BoldItalicFeatures={Extension=.otf},
            BoldItalicFont = LinLibertine_RBI]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}

[{\bfseries\slshape 6}]

\end{document}
```

### Addition

*Wrong* font means that xelatex finds a *different* font than lualatex. `LinLibertine_RZI.otf` is the italic semibold variant of libertine.

But that the font gives wrong old style numbers is not xelatex faults, it happens with luatex too if one force it to use the font. This is cleary a defect in the font and so I added a bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxlibertine/bugs/331/

Comment: Thanks for the through explanation I will go over it. So is it always safer to load fonts by the exact file name like `fontname.ttf` or `fontname.otf`?

Comment: Yes, if you want complete control file name are better. But by font name is often faster.