# Libertine package options with boldface and emphasis change numeric text

Tags: libertine, package-options

I've just installed and updated MacTeX and am recompiling files for the university courses I'm teaching this year.

I'm experiencing a really peculiar problem with numeric information when I set certain options on the `Libertine` package and combine that with bold face with emphasis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[oldstyle,sb]{libertine}

\begin{document}
1,048,576 vs.\ \emph{\textbf{1,048,576}}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

If I get rid of either option on the libertine package, the problem goes away. It makes no difference, by the way, whether `\emph{}` is imbedded in `\textbf{}` or the other way around, for what it's worth.

Any idea what is going on?

I don't *think* I had this problem last year, but I don't have access to the older system at the moment though I can check this later if need be.

Comment: eek that's not good! I get the same here... (same in tl 2017 and 2016)

Comment: You didn't happen to scan those number with a Xerox photocopier (http://www.dkriesel.com/en/blog/2013/0802_xerox-workcentres_are_switching_written_numbers_when_scanning), did you? I can reproduce the issue with the `libertine` package and all three engines. No matter what comes out of this question, you will want to **contact the package author about this**, he should know about this.

Comment: No, I didn't scan it! Wish I could cop to this :) Sent a message to the package maintainer just now.

Comment: For the otf version of the font there is already a bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxlibertine/bugs/331/, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372441/compilation-with-xetex-yields-wrong-chapter-number/372529#372529

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the reference. I thought I read somewhere earlier today that the OTF version was obsolete... but I don't recall where. Is there a reason to prefer one package over the other?

Comment: Why should otf be obsolete? The otf version of the font is used with xelatex and lualatex, but your example (if compiled with pdflatex) shows that the type1 fonts have the same problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I never said it myself (in fact I was using those fonts last year)... I read something about this somewhere, but don't remember where. That's why I asked. Not of great importance.

Comment: Avoid italic boldface: as you see it causes depreciation. 

Comment: @egreg Rest assured that I use it sparingly ordinarily. This is a special case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux Libertine otf font has the problem (as shown if you run xelatex).  But it seems that the libertinus fork has fixed the problem, if you're willing to use xelatex.

Comment: I do use XeLaTeX anyway so this may be an option. I had considered this package at one point and don't remember why I didn't go that route. I'll check it out!

Comment: I've been in touch with the Libertine package maintainer and as the problem is with the fonts themselves he has suggested I contact the font designer(s), which I may do for completeness' sake (though as Ulrike notes the problem has already been signaled for OTF). In the mean time, he also recommends Libertinus.