# Math arrows don't display with Beamer + xelatexmk + libertinus

Tags: beamer, xetex, libertinus

I have `beamer` presentations I've been using for some years in class. This year, I discovered problems with the `libertine` package and following advice from this forum ([Libertine package options with boldface and emphasis change numeric text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448700/libertine-package-options-with-boldface-and-emphasis-change-numeric-text)) switched to `libertinus`. I now find that the various math arrows in my presentations fail to display.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
%EDIT: inserting \usefonttheme{professional fonts} here avoids the problem
\usepackage{libertinus}% works fine with libertine

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame name}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is text.
\item Rightarrow ($\Rightarrow$)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have determined that

1. replacing `libertinus` with `libertine` works fine; or
2. replacing `xelatexmk` with `pdflatexmk` works fine; or
3. replacing `beamer` with (say) article works fine.

It *seems* to be this particular combination.

`xelatexmk` was part of the `MacTeX` bistro and moved from the inactive engines folder. I do need `XeLaTeX` but perhaps this is no longer the way to do this?

I am curious as to the nature of the conflict....

EDIT: the suggestion by jfbu below does indeed solve my problem. From the `beamer` documentation regarding `professionalfonts`:

> Beamer normally replaces certain character glyphs in mathematical text by more appropriate versions. .... If your professional font package takes care of this already, Beamer’s meddling should be switched off [by using `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`].

I still wonder why the problem was introduced in this specific combination, however! (but can live in ignorance if need be :) )

EDIT #2: It would appear that the `beamer` package issue which I reported earlier today has already been addressed ([Turn off font substitution for unicode-math](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/5725bc5b888a21ede7b8dcc276b1472e4466565f)) and should be implemented shortly. In effect, `beamers changes will be also suppressed when a unicode-math is loaded.

Comment: you may raise a ticket on the [beamer issue tracker](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer) asking that the maintainer adds `libertinus` to the list of packages automatically triggering the equivalent of `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`.

Comment: I've just posted it (issue #508) as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{libertinus}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame name}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is text.
\item Rightarrow ($\Rightarrow$)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=xelatex 2018.9.21)  22 SEP 2018 19:25
```

Comment: putting the thing in a box one can confirm `.\TU/libertinusmath-regular.otf(1)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1974` it uses good font. (`\showoutput` does not work in beamer frame!)

Comment: It got pointed out to me that `\showouput` works if one inserts it before `\begin{document}` for example...